# second person into third person

Tags: tenses, third-person

How do I put "let's start with the year 1688" into third person? I need this for my history paper. I tried googling it but nothing helpful came up. Maybe one of you guys can help?

Comment: Why does it matter to you whether someone uses third person or not?  (And, in particular, who is the third person here?)

Comment: First, _Let's start with `X`_ is not second-person. _Let's_ is an idiom that contains a **first**-person pronoun _us_ (an inclusive first-person plural). Second, invitations starting with the idiom _Let's_ don't get "put into third person". What in the world would it mean to put that utterance into third person? Can you give us any examples of other such transformations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a matter of *person*, but rather one of *mood*. Your sentence is imperative, telling the reader what to do. The analogous third person "Let him/her/it/them start with the year 1688" makes no sense in this context.

In general, you should avoid the imperative mood in a history paper. You shouldn't be talking to your reader, you should be recounting facts and analysis to him or her. For this, use the indicative mood. For example you could write

> The Nine Years' War began in the year 1688.

Of course, replace "The Nine Years' War" with a more appropriate topic.

Comment: Let ***they*** start ?